# fastercsv - save object table in one go (ruby)

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

I read my csv using the line below

```
data = FCSV.table("test.csv", {:quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true, :return_headers => false, :header_converters => :downcase, :converters => :all} )
```

### QUESTION

**Can I save object `data` in the same manner (one line, one go + csv options)?** *see above*

I sort the table (see the code below) and then I want so save it again. I couldn't work out how to save the table in one go. I know how to do it row by row though.

```
array_of_arrays = data.to_a()
headers = array_of_arrays.shift # remove the headers
array_of_arrays.sort_by {|e| [e[3], e[4].to_s, e[1]]} .each {|line| p line }
array_of_arrays.insert(0,headers)
```

Anything I tried did not work and gave me something very similar to

```
csv.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'
... FCSV.table("sorted.csv","w" {:quote_char => '"', :col_sep =...
```

### NOTE:

Please note that I want to use all the CSV options when saving the file `{:quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true, :return_headers => false, :header_converters => :downcase, :converters => :all}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've got an array of arrays in data, it looks like you can just do:

```
FCSV::Table.new(data).to_csv
```

to get all the csv for data as a string, then output that back to the file.

Comment: @dunedain289: and the bit `back to the file` is something I am asking about

Answer (score 2):

Just following up on what dunedain said, the following will write the file out

```
@csv = FCSV::Table.new(data).to_csv
File.open("modified_csv.csv", 'w') {|f| f.write(@csv) }
```

also the error you had in the code below is because you didnt have a comma after the "w" and before the { but it looks like you were perhaps tring to the reader functions instead of the writer functions

```
csv.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'
... FCSV.table("sorted.csv","w" {:quote_char => '"', :col_sep =...
```

Comment: @Adam: thank for the comma thing.FCSV.table takes only two arguments not three so I won't work anyway. Please note that I want to save csv file and use csv options at the same time.

Comment: no probs, can you post some more code around the FCSV.table("sorted.csv" .... not just the errors?